# update the value of select box with php mysql jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm facing major issue in changing `status` in `<select>` tag to database through jquery-ajax.

Note : I have searched in stackoverflow for this question. but those answere not come close to my question. Here are those links below
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915126/how-to-update-select-boxes-with-php-mysql-jquery-ajax), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753613/dynamically-updating-select-boxes-with-php-mysql-aja), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894033/changing-the-value-of-a-select-box-with-jquery)

When i click on first  row select box the data is sent through ajax and the `status column in table` get  updated and also it is updated in mysql database.
But when is select 2nd, 3rd row it  doesn't change  not update  the `status column` in html page nor in database here is the output image.
[image: output image]

Thank you in advance..

Here is the details of my code
database table name: ajaxselect
[image: Table image from database]

HTML file: index.php

```
 <?php
    include('processing.php');
    $newobj = new processing();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jquery Ajax select <tag> with PHP Mysql</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Product name</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <?php echo $newobj->display();?>
        </table>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#selectstatus").change(function(){
                    var statusname = $("#selectstatus").val();                  
                    var getid = $("#getid").val();                  
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'ajaxreceiver.php',
                        data:{statusname:statusname,getid
                        :getid},
                        success:function(result){
                            $("#display").html(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ajax file : ajaxreceiver.php

```
 <?php
    include('processing.php');
    $newobj = new processing();

    if(isset($_POST['statusname'],$_POST['getid'])){
        $statusid = $_POST['statusname'];
        $id = $_POST['getid'];

        $newobj->getdata($statusid,$id);
    }
?>
```

PHP class file : processing.php

```
    <?php
    class processing{
        private $link;

        function __construct(){
            $this->link= new mysqli('localhost','root','','example');
            if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
                die ("connection failed".mysqli_connect_errno());
            }
        }

        function display(){
            $sql = $this->link->stmt_init();
            $id=1;
            if($sql->prepare("SELECT id,productname,status FROM ajaxselect")){
                $sql->bind_result($id,$productname,$status);
                if($sql->execute()){
                    while($sql->fetch()){   
            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="hidden" id="getid" value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $id;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $productname;?></td>
                            <td><p id="display"><?php echo $status;?></p></td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="selectstatus">
                                    <option>Pending</option>
                                    <option>Delivered</option>
                                    <option>Cancelled</option>
                                    <option>Amount Paid</option>    
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
            <?php   
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function getdata($statusid,$id){
            $sql = $this->link->stmt_init();
            if($sql->prepare("UPDATE ajaxselect SET status=? WHERE id=?")){
                $sql->bind_param('si',$statusid,$id);
                if($sql->execute()){
                    echo $statusid;
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Update Failed";
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: All of your select boxes have the same ID?

Comment: No they are dynamically changing see the code is in processing.php page `<input type="hidden" id="getid" value="<?php echo $id;?>` i have just hidden the input value. but they can be fetched and how to do so

Comment: Yes, but you are checking always the same ID. I posted an answer, so you can try it.

Comment: There are so many things wrong I don't know where to start... first off... you can't have more than 1 ID, use classes. Second, you always get the same field... which is why you are always updating the first record... The guy above me had the right idea but his answer is wrong too. You need to add the ID to the attribute and then just get it with $(this).attr(data-id) or something like that or store it all in an js object.

Comment: Post your HTML for Product List instead of Image. Issue is just because of ID's you  have used, the script is updating same row again and again. Please use classes, or extract values by using jQuery/javascript object

Comment: I'm facing the problem in extracting

Comment: When the event on change trigger it must take the value of ID= getid to fetch value. But how

Comment: @armin can you paste the answers here

Comment: @Chris Thanks for reminding me to check my answer. I focused only one one part of the code, forgot to check the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your select-boxes have the same id, so `$("#selectstatus").val()` will return always the same value. You should get value of changed element. Javascript: `this.value` or jQuery `$(this).val()`
Example (notice that `selectstatus` is a class, so you should add a new class):
HTML

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $productname;?></td>
    <td><p id="display"><?php echo $status;?></p></td>
     <td>
         <select status-id="<?php echo $id;?>" class="selectstatus" id="selectstatus">
            <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
            <option value="Delivered">Delivered</option>
            <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
            <option value="Amount paid">Amount Paid</option>    
         </select>
     </td>
   </tr>
```

JS

```
$(".selectstatus").change(function(){
     var statusname = $(this).val();                  
     var getid = $(this).attr("status-id");                  
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'ajaxreceiver.php',
                    data:{statusname:statusname,getid
                    :getid},
                    success:function(result){
                        $("#display").html(result);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Thank for solution but their is another problem when i change the values of `<select>` box it changes the status of the particular row in database that good but it displays the output only in first row.

Comment: i have asked question in this link related to my above comment [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480310/update-rows-status-with-jquery-change-and-display-i-respective-tableissue) . You can read the question their and can get an idea of my question . THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: I will check it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use an id in that case or it will work only for the first occurence

`

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".selectstatus").change(function(){
                    var statusname = $(this).val();                  
                    var getid = $(this).parent().parent().children().eq(0).children().eq(0).val();                  
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'ajaxreceiver.php',
                        data:{statusname:statusname,getid
                        :getid},
                        success:function(result){
                            $("#display").html(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

`